# flink: getting byte[] data from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, snappy, apache-flink

Im using **flink-1.0-SNAPSHOT** to consume data from kafka. The data is coming in as **Snappy compressed** byte[] that gets passed to thrift for later use.

When I use **flink** to retrieve the data it's getting corrupted or mishandled somehow such that it can't be decompressed. Code is derived from [this](https://github.com/dataArtisans/kafka-example) sample and is as follows:

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer081<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {

    @Override public String map(String value) throws Exception {
    boolean bvalid = Snappy.isValidCompressedBuffer(value.getBytes());
 });
```

The *isValidCompressedBuffer* returns false every time.

The data is known to be good when consumed via other avenues.

What did I miss?

---

### Solution:

Im posting this as I couldn't find any examples that used `RawSchema`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create execution environment
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // parse user parameters
    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    DataStream<byte[]> dataStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer081<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new RawSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

    dataStream.map(new MapFunction<byte[], Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object map(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
            boolean bvali = Snappy.isValidCompressedBuffer(bytes);

            });
            return 0;
        }
    }).print();
    env.execute();
}
```

Comment: How do you feed in the data into Kafka?

Comment: Some producer from some other part of the company that I have no control over. Suffice to say that I can read the data using other means so I know the format. Am wanting to get this working via **flink** so I can compare the flow rate to our existing pipeline.

Comment: Kafka does snappy compression out of the box. You do not need to decompress data - Consumers get decompressed data.

Comment: @AnatolyDeyneka - that hasn't been my experience up to this point. I send thrift objects into Kafka and use a decompress->deserialize process to get the bits on the consumer side. It's been that way (for me at least) for as long as we've used Kafka.

Comment: ok. As I understand you do not use kafka compression and you put already compressed objects. In that case problem can be in 'String value'. It's not correct to read bytes as String. Could you change it to map(byte[] value) and try again?

Comment: @AnatolyDeyneka That seems to have been the issue. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it. I'm putting the code snip into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading byte-messages as String is incorrect.
You should read bytes as is and then decompress:

```
public Object map(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    boolean bvalid = Snappy.isValidCompressedBuffer(bytes);
    ...
```